# Why assign a value within a function's arguments?

Tags: javascript

I've come across this pattern in an open-source project and have never come across it before, and was wondering the reasoning for doing it:

```
doSomething(blah = blurgh);
```

Comment: Because you can do an assignment and use that value as an argument for that function. Though it's not a common pattern

Comment: Optional Parameters maybe https://www.dotnetperls.com/optional-parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a shortcut to do in a single statement : assigning a variable and using   the assigned variable as argument of a function.

So instead of writing it :

```
blah = blurgh;
doSomething(blah);
```

You write just :

```
doSomething(blah = blurgh);
```

Answer (score 1):

It assigns it as a default value for the argument:

```
function someFunc(thing = "default string") {
  console.log(thing);
}

someFunc() // default string
someFunc('another string') // another string
```

You can assign anything you want as the default value, even a previous argument

```
function someFunc(arg1, arg2 = ar1) {...}
```

It will use the default value even if you pass null explicitly.

Comment: I posted basically this answer, but deleted it when I realised the OP is referring to a function *call*: `doSomething(blah = blurgh);`, not a function definition. This may be the reason for the downvote.